# popup menu and menuItem to display list of items

Tags: python, maya

I have created a button, when it is click, it will displays a popup menu showing the list of cameras created along with persp camera (top, front, side camera will not be displayed)

While it seems to work, but as soon as I create another new camera, I got this error citing `# TypeError: Too many objects or values. #` and it is pointing towards the `cmds.popupMenu(a)`

Is there a better way to rectify it?

```
class orientCameraUI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(orientCameraUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300,225)
        self.initUI()
        self.createConnections()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('OrientControl UI')

        self.getCurrentCamBtn = QPushButton('Get current CAM')
        gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.getCurrentCamBtn, 0, 1)
        self.setLayout(gridLayout)

    def createConnections(self):
        self.connect(self.getCurrentCamBtn, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.getCurrentCam)

    def getCurrentCam(self):
        # createdCams - camera1, camera2 etc.
        createdCams = cmds.ls(cameras = True, visible = True)
        getPersp = cmds.ls("persp")
        cmds.popupMenu( button=1 )
        cmds.popupMenu(createdCams)
        cmds.popupMenu(getPersp)
```

Comment: Well, what's in `a`? Are there a huge number of values returned by that `ls`?

Comment: @abarnert Edited my post hopefully it gives a clearer view. `a` lists the created cameras. It works if I created a new camera, but as soon as the number of created cameras is more than 1, an error occurs

Comment: Is `a` actually a `list` then? Because [the docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/popupMenu.html) make it pretty clear that the argument to `popupMenu` is supposed to be a string. Maybe you just need `','.join(a)` or `','.join(map(str, a))`?

Comment: It does not seems to be working though

Comment: _What_ does not seem to be working? What did you try? What happened? And what are the answers to the questions I asked in the last comment?

Comment: I tried your method using the example scene I got from this link - http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/popupMenu.html, there isn't any popup menu items at all when clicking onto the button. Its as though it is empty though cameras are indeed created in the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this snippet of your code here:

```
cmds.popupMenu( button=1 )
cmds.popupMenu(createdCams)
cmds.popupMenu(getPersp)
```

The first line creates a popup menu. (`button=1` tells it to open when you click with the left mouse button instead of the default right mouse button.)

You haven't added any menu items to the menu. Calling `popupMenu` again with a list of items is trying to make a new *menu*, not new *items*.

Instead, what you want is a `menuItem`.
But you need a different menu item for each created cam. You can't pass a list of cameras into *one* `menuItem` command. Use a `for` loop to make as many as you need:

```
cmds.popupMenu(button=1) # creates the menu
for cam in createdCams:  # loop over createdCams assigning to cam one at a time
    cmds.menuItem(cam)   # creates one menu item for cam
cmds.menuItem(getPersp)  # create one menu item for persp
```

See the documentation on [`popupMenu`](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/popupMenu.html) and [`menuItem`](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/menuItem.html)

Comment: just wondering if it is possible to integrate this into PyQt QPushButton?